# Given two quadratic forms, find an isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, isometry

Let $q_1(x)$ and $q_2(x)$, be two quadratic forms on a vector space $V$ based on $\mathbb{R}$. In the base $\mathcal{B} = (e_1, e_2, e_3)$, the expressions of the two forms are:

$$
\begin{align}
& q_1(x) = 3x_1^2 - 24x_1x_2 + 12x_1x_3 + 48x_2^2 - 52x_2x_3 + 12x_3^2 \\
& q_2(x) = x_1^2 + 2x_1x_2 + 2x_2^2 - 2x_2x_3 - x_3^2
\end{align}
$$

I have to give the expression of $\lambda : V \to V : x \mapsto \lambda(x)$, an isometry of $(V,q_1)$ in $(V,q_2)$.

First, I figured out that $q_1$ and $q_2$ was the same quadratic form $q$, expressed in two different basis, because of the signature of $q_1$ and $q_2$. Thus, find an isometry is equivalent to find $\lambda$ represented in $\mathbb R^3_3$ by the matrix $\Lambda$, such that this equality holds true:

$$ G_1 = \Lambda^TG_2\Lambda $$

Where $G_i$ is the matrix representing $g_{q_i}$, the polar form of $q_i$, in the base $\mathcal B$.

1) Is my reasoning correct about the the quadratic form $q$ and the isometry $\lambda$ ?
2) If it is true, how can I find the matrix $\Lambda$ ?
3) If it is false, how am I supposed to give the expression of $\lambda$ ?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: So, you claim you have found the eigenbases $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ for $q_1$ and $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ for $q_2$, and the eigenvalues match. Then, putting the bases into column vectors, we obtain matrices $B$ and $C$, and what you're looking for simply maps $b_i\mapsto c_i$, thus it is $\Lambda =CB^{-1}$.

Comment: Kierkhoffen, what book is this from?  @Berci  both characteristic polynomials are irreducible with three irrational roots. There are ways to solve $G_1 = P^T G_2 P$ but this is not a task for the squeamish

Comment: @Berci I figured out this solution soon after publishing my question. However, it is not necessary to "get back" to the base $\mathcal B$.

Comment: @WillJagy This exercise comes from a list given by my teaching assistant.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer to your own question, then.